# Thread safety with a shared collection

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have read many articles about syncing threads, lock statements and race conditions (with C#). Unfortunately, some of it is refusing to be fully understood by my brain.

I have a situation where I have a shared object containing `Lists<>` of different classes designed to read, write, create and delete database records. This object is shared between different threads during its lifetime (the lifetime of the application) - my problem is I cannot work out how I should protect/lock this object so it can always be safely manipulated without corrupting data.

I already see a problem occur infrequently - sometimes blank database rows will get saved - I assume this is to do with another thread altering the object between the '`INSERT`' and '`UPDATE`' database queries in the classes Save() method.

My feeling is that an appropriate `lock` is the solution, but I can't work out where this should be.

Any help or insights in to where I've gone wrong are massively appreciated!

Comment: Did you forget to include your code? We can't find out what's wrong without it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read about the new System.Collections.Concurrent namespace available in .net 4.0 framework. This namespace provides several tread-safe collection classes...

Here is the link to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page